# С разной периодичностью, падает mysql (крэш таблицы,ошибка в описании). Подскажите как побороть?

Tags: php, debian, mysql

Раз в день или неделю, периодичность разная, падает mysql, а точнее таблица "крэшится".
На белом экране:

```
Table './site/f4p5_session' is marked as crashed and should be repaired SQL=INSERT INTO `f4p5_session` (`session_id`, `client_id`, `time`) VALUES ('hf264h23hy23d723364dh3', 0, '2534534545')
```

Почему она падает? Работает же! Причем может сайт работать неделю, две иногда и три. Но бывает раз в день в течении недели может так падать. 
Пока что лечу так:

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --all-databases
```

Но сайт лежит пока не замечу ошибку. Нужно как-то ее локализовать. Заранее спасибо за наводки! Буду признателен любой помощи.

Comment: Форсированная перезагрузка (ребут ресетом) произошла. Или сегфолт в инстансе mysql сервера. в первом случае - чинится административными методами (сменить хостера например), во втором - вдумчиво читаем логи (особенно лог самого mysql, dmesg) ищем segfault, oop, sig11

Comment: Все логи mysql которые я только нашел, не содержат в себе абсолютно ничего. Никаких ошибок и сообщений.

Comment: Для чого база даних f4p5_session?

Comment: системные смотрели ? какая OS вообще ?

Comment: debian стоит. f4p5_session - это таблица, хранящая сессии пользователей